# OOB Filter Options for Managed Metadata in Sp2013

Tags: metadata

I am looking for a filter option that allows us to filter data based on Metadata values . I am using SP2013 on Office 365 and as well On Premise SP2013 .

I have tried using SharePoint List Filter,Text Filter,Choice Filter.List View Filter but none of this options support Managed Metadata Filter

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I've found so far is a plug in that provides this type of support (I think) - It's licensed by Sapiens - see http://www.sharepointsapiens.com/list-filter-web-part/details/features/.

I'm looking for an OOB feature that allows Site Metadata to be used in the SharePoint List Filter as well - it seems as if this should be possible and even fundamental to a useful curated SharePoint site...